# Looking for BSC RPC Provider with Log Monitoring

Tags: contract-development, json-rpc, testnets, bsc

I'm in search of a reliable RPC provider for accessing the Binance Smart Chain (BSC) network, preferably with log monitoring capabilities similar to Alchemy. Any recommendations or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can try using QuickNode RPC (https://dashboard.quicknode.com/endpoints/new/bsc).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try Chainstack: https://chainstack.com/build-better-with-bnb-smart-chain/

Disclaimer: I'm the founder of Chainstack